# Default Parameters versus In-Class Member Initialization versus Delegating Constructors

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to make a decision about which method I should mainly use to construct complex objects with multiple constructors.

**So what are the pros and cons of default parameters, in-class member initialization and delegating constructors wrt each others?**

**DEFAULT PARAMETERS**

```
class DefaultParams
{
public:
  DefaultParams(int a = 42,
                const std::string &b = "42")
                :
                m_a(a),
                m_b(b)
  {
    // DO THINGS
  };

  DefaultParams(const std::string &b)
    :
    m_a(42),
    m_b(b)
  {
    // DO THINGS
  };

private:
  int m_a;
  std::string m_b;
};
```

PROS: less constructors;
CONS: Repeat code or need an Init() method.

**IN-CLASS INITIALIZATION**

```
class InClass
{
public:
  InClass()
  {
    // DO THINGS
  };

  InClass(int a)
    : 
    m_a(a)
  {
    // DO THINGS
  };

  InClass(const std::string &b)
    :
    m_b(b)
  {
    // DO THINGS
  };

  InClass(int a,
          const std::string &b)
    :
    m_a(a),
    m_b(b)
  {
    // DO THINGS
  };

private:
  int m_a = 42;
  std::string m_b = "42";
};
```

PROS: ?
CONS: more contructors, repeat code or need an Init() method.

**DELEGATING CONSTRUCTORS**

```
class DelegatingCTor
{
public:
  DelegatingCTor()
    :
    DelegatingCTor(42, "42")
  {
  };

  DelegatingCTor(int a)
    :
    DelegatingCTor(a, "42")
  {
  };

  DelegatingCTor(const std::string &b)
    :
    DelegatingCTor(42, b)
  {
  };

  DelegatingCTor(int a, const std::string &b)
    :
    m_a(a),
    m_b(b)
  {
    // DO THINGS
  };

private:
  int m_a;
  std::string m_b;
};
```

PROS: do not repeat code;
CONS: more constructors.

Of course, there are a lot more. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to consider the destructor as well. Once a constructor has executed, the object is considered constructed and the destructor will run (better exception safety).

Comment: Default parameters and in-class initialization are two orthagonal concepts. A function (constructor or not) argument doesn't have to match any member variable.

Comment: I prefer the delegated constructors. More less-repeated code is better in my opinion.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: not that orthogonal I believe. Because default parameters can be used in place of in-class initialization as shown in my question. Now in practice, maybe it is better to avoid default parameters in ctor, I don't know.

Comment: Defaults can cause implicit casts and temporaries if you're not careful